# Ghc: partially compile Haskell code?

Tags: haskell, ghci

When I compile a Haskell file with `ghci`, typically with `:load`, and if there is no type error, all the expressions are loaded in the ghc interpreter. It's very nice: I can play around with `:t` to figure out the type of various expressions.

My problem is: if there is a tiny error somewhere, ghci is not able to load *anything* (not even the imported modules!!), which makes finding the right types even more difficult. I always do the same: comment out all the bits that do not typecheck, find the relevant types wiht `:t` in ghci, and de-comment.

But this is so tedious! Is there a better workflow for "partially compiling" a Haskell source code?

Comment: [`:set -fdefer-type-errors`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/defer-type-errors.html)

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov create answer with links :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @MikhailGlushenkov pointed out in the comments, the solution is to use the [`-fdefer-type-errors`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/defer-type-errors.html) flag to GHCi.

Comment: Oh my god *I need this*.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz  I was pretty excited about it too, instant addition to my .ghci file